# Counting the records in a certain table and displaying the results

Tags: php, mysql, count

would this be the correct way to display the number or records in a particular table, I am just going to put this in an if statement so if there are more than 20 do something ?

```
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mytable"); 
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 

 echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(1)`

generally both will work, the difference is that `COUNT(*)` counts number of matched rows and `COUNT(something)` calculates number of matched rows for which `something` is not null. To clarify, given a table:

```
 test
 a     b
 1     2
 NULL  3
 2     4

 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test; -- 3
 SELECT COUNT(a) FROM test; -- 2
 SELECT COUNT(b) FROM test; -- 3
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, good to know there are several options for anything else I need to do :-) .